# Python selenium no permission to access this server on browser.get()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, access-denied

I am running a selenium code to access this link:

http://www.hipercor.es/supermercado/0110118613501925-schweppes-tonica-original-100-aromas-naturales-botella-20-cl-envase-de-vidrio/

But get an error: `You don't have permission to access LINK on this server.`
Is there a work around to load this page? Going through `requests.get()` instead of selenium also times out.

I have read a few posts about it, mainly using the `user-agent` however it did not solve the issue.

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.517 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
```

Comment: If the server you are trying to reach actively tries to block scraping - I'd feel its a bit unethical to try and prevent that.

Comment: seems like the given link can only be accessed on a specific private network.

Comment: You can try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver

Comment: Tried profiles and undetected-chromedriver - all failed.

Comment: And when you reload the page with using the dirvers mentioned?

Comment: no luck either way. sometimes it works after I load other pages, but only for a few calls and goes back to the same issues.